# Amazon pay return error on checkout page

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-gateway, onestepcheckout

on my Magento store sometimes customer facing the error on the checkout page when the customer wants to place the order with Amazon pay payment method.

It says "

**Important Message
We're sorry, but there's a problem processing the order from this website.
Please contact the seller for help with placing this order."**

**Steps that I followed:**

1) Added product into Car

2) Login into Amazon

3) From Amazon checkout navigated to home page.

4) Again came back to Amazon checkout & found this error & at this time following errors were there in the console:

```
"Uncaught Error: Unable to process binding "foreach: function()

{return $parent.elems() }
"" (Attaching screenshot for error)
```

**I am using Magento 2.2.4 with PHP 7.1.20**

[image]

Thanks In advance..!!!

Comment: It's knockout js error, you need to check ajax call and find and investigate in which ajax call getting the error .

Comment: @Dhrumin can you suggest,how can i prvents that error?

Comment: You need to check in browser console with inspect element.